# Antisocial Disorder and Art

Tags: personality-disorder

If people with Antisocial Disorder are generally lacking of emotions and empathy, do they understand art in a way as neurotypical people does?
Are there any famous artists who been diagnosed with ADR?

Comment: https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/31144853 Above I have attached an article which should answer your question